# Tabs panel in Google Chrome fullscreen mode

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, tabs, fullscreen

Is it possible to have a tabs panel in Fullscreen Mode in Google Chrome?

I know the option of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> / <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> commands.

I would prefer Google-created solutions, for compatibility and safety.

Comment: Can you explain what a "tabs panel" is so we know what it is you want?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no tab list or panel in fullscreen mode that is offered in Google Chrome natively. If there was one, you would see it.

Your only option is a third-party plugin such as [Fullscreen Tab List](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fullscreen-tab-list/dcfkdnellogpollhnffekiljjnebdlld), but as you have said you don't want non-Google software, you've locked yourself out of a viable solution.